# PostgreSQL: some troubles with getting data from json

Tags: postgresql

I try to get some data from JSON from PostgreSQL column:

```
CREATE TABLE source_redshift.staticprompts (
    id              INT,
    projectid       BIGINT,
    scriptid        INT,
    promptnum       INT,
    prompttype      VARCHAR(20),
    inputs          VARCHAR(2000),
    attributes      VARCHAR(2000),
    text            VARCHAR(2000),
    corpuscode      VARCHAR(2000),
    comment         VARCHAR(2000),
    created         TIMESTAMP,
    modified        TIMESTAMP


);
```

JSON in 'inputs' column:

```
{"inputs":[{"name": "ambient","desc": "Select from below the ambient setting that best decribe your environment right now","values": ["Indoor - Loud", "Indoor - Normal", "Indoor - Whisper", "Outdoor - Loud", "Outdoor - Normal", "Outdoor - Whisper", "Semi-Outdoor - Loud", "Semi-Outdoor - Normal", "Semi-Outdoor - Whisper"]}]}
```

Query:

```
SELECT json_extract_path_text(inputs::json,'inputs','desc') AS desc
FROM source_redshift.staticprompts;
```

But I get nothing in desc - no data, nulls

Comment: Optimization: If `inputs` is always in json format you should really think about converting the VARCHAR to JSONB and avoid doing huge/lot casting operations on your DB.

Comment: When I try to use SELECT inputs::json#>>'{inputs}' FROM source_redshift.staticprompts; I get "[{"name": "ambient","desc": "Select from below the ambient setting that best decribe your environment right now","values": ["Indoor - Loud", "Indoor - Normal", "Indoor - Whisper", "Outdoor - Loud", "Outdoor - Normal", "Outdoor - Whisper", "Semi-Outdoor - Loud", "Semi-Outdoor - Normal", "Semi-Outdoor - Whisper"]}]". But when I try to use SELECT inputs::json#>>'{inputs,desc}' FROM source_redshift.staticprompts; - I get null

Comment: the function in general is correctly called. The path will be inputs.desc. Maybe you can rename your column on DB side and mapp in to the application if you want it be called `desc`. That's a blocked literal you can't use on Postgres. Think about calling this field description like it should be called. Never shortern fieldnames. Even bad practice on jsons.

Comment: Fixed with adding 0 element from list: inputs::jsonb#>>'{inputs,0,desc}' AS desc

Comment: Alternative `inputs::jsonb -> 'inputs' -> 0 ->> 'desc' as desc`

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed it with `inputs::jsonb#>>'{inputs,0,desc}' AS desc`